# matplotlib plot a matrix of unbalanced axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a matrix of size `>>> X.shape (2194, 100) >>>`  I would like to plot it on square. How can I do that?

This is what I have tried

```
plt.matshow(X)
plt.show()
```

but the figure respects the ratio of the axis. I would like instead a squared figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plt.imshow(X, aspect='auto', interpolation='None')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This should give you what you want

Comment: @Donbeo Sorry, tried the different aspect arguments and copied the wrong line. Try this one